# Python setuptools AttributeError when reading in setup.cfg configuration

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following `setup.py` file:

```
import setuptools
import setuptools.config

_CONFIG = setuptools.config.read_configuration('setup.cfg')

setuptools.setup(
    **_CONFIG
    )
```

...and `setup.cfg` file:

```
[metadata]
name = Example
version = 1.0.0
author = First Last
author_email = first.last@example.com
home_page = https://www.github.com/firstlast/example
description = Example is an example project.
long_description = file: README.md
license_file = LICENSE
platform = any
keywords = example
classifiers =
  Programming Language :: Python
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7
  License :: Other/Proprietary License
  Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
zip_safe = False
include_package_data = True
python_requires = >= 2.7, != 3.0.*, != 3.1.*, != 3.2.*
packages =
  example
setup_requires =
  setuptools
install_requires =
  requests

[options.extras_require]
dev =
  ipython
```

In order to install the module, I'm doing the following:

1. Create a virtual environment with *pipenv*.

   ```
   $ pipenv --three
   ```
2. Activate the virtual environment.

   ```
   $ pipenv shell
   ```
3. **Try** to install the *example* module in the virtual environment.

   ```
   $ pip install .
   ```

When I perform step #3, I get the following error:

```
Processing /Users/firstlast/Stuff/learn/python/setuptools/example
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/jw/f2zw3cls6xj20dld1h8st4jc0000gp/T/pip-req-build-rcbbm11x/setup.py", line 37, in <module>
        **_CONFIG
      File "/Users/firstlast/.local/share/virtualenvs/example-tYFXe0D0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 140, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Users/firstlast/.local/share/virtualenvs/example-tYFXe0D0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 370, in __init__
        k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 251, in __init__
        for (opt, val) in cmd_options.items():
    AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'items'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jw/f2zw3cls6xj20dld1h8st4jc0000gp/T/pip-req-build-rcbbm11x/
```

It seems that *setuptools* is using the value specified by `zip_file` as a dictionary, when in reality it is a boolean.

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

**NOTE**

The version of Python installed in the virtual environment by `pipenv --three` is Python 3.7.

I've confirmed that within the virtual environment, *setuptools* is up-to-date (i.e. `pip install --upgrade setuptools` => "Requirement already up-to-date: ... (40.4.3)"), as well as *pip* itself (i.e. `pip --version` == 18.0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how `setup.cfg` is used.  `read_configuration()` is only for use by non-setuptools code that wants to read `setup.cfg`; there's no need to call it in your own `setup.py`, because `setup()` does the reading & processing of `setup.cfg` itself.  Just change your `setup.py` to:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup()
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! Sorry for the stupid question. I skimmed through the _setuptools_ "readthedocs", but I found it somewhat unclear.